# running several background threads in succession on iphone / ipad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have to download a ton of images and I am doing it on a background thread, problem is all of the downloaded data is not released until I go back to the main thread which is fine a for couple hundred images but when I get into thousands the app runs out of memory and crashes.

So I need to run several background threads in succession so I can batch the download of the images in groups of say 200 so my autorelease pools can clear and memory gets released.

I cannot wrap my head around how to do this. I need some sort of recursive function on the main thread to call the background threads with and keep track of the batches so it knows which to call next. I know that passing values back and forth between threads will cause me some problems so I am not sure how to approach this?

Anyone tackle a problem like this before?

Comment: Something that may help is to create your own autorelease pool in the thread and then release whenever you get to a certain limit.  This way, you have some control over how much is being processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to wait for everything to download before releasing memory.  You could just pass each image or small batch of images to the main thread using performSelectorOnMainThread, and let the main thread release memory as it caches the data in storage or uses the data.  Then continue on in the background thread until done and pass a "done" message, again using performSelectorOnMainThread.

Comment: how do you pass arguments in the @selector for going to the main thread?  Can you do that?

Comment: Yes, you can do that using withObject:

Answer (score 1):

NSOperationQueues solve this problem for you.  You create a class that descends from NSOperation that does the download for you.  You then create an NSOperationQueue and add the downloads to the queue. You can control the max concurrency of the queue, etc.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/index.html

Comment: I used hotpaw2's answer with great success but I think I need to re-think it using NSOperationQueue

Answer (score 0):

Use NSInvocationOperation. tht wuld fix the issue instead of splitting the code in chunks. here is the sample i used

```
NSOperationQueue *downloadQueue = [NSOperationQueue new]; for (Product *cProduct in productsMasterArray) {
NSInvocationOperation *downloadOperation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(downloadImages:) object:cProduct.ITEM_CODE]; [downloadQueue addOperation:downloadOperation]; [downloadOperation release]; }
```